# How to induce an iOS 7 background terminate/kill to test an application

Tags: ios, ios7, voip

When testing a VOIP or a background fetch application, testing against background termination and launch is vital to see if the desired outcome is achieved. Right now, launching 28 applications including five games doesn't show any applications being killed due to memory hogs. The five games are NBA GM, CEASAR SLOTS, STELLA WARS, CRASH DRIVE 2, WATER 2.

What needs to be checked is, if any applications get killed on low memory conditions. Any ideas on triggering that kind of condition?

(VOIP apps won't be killed if the socket is active, but why aren't any applications getting killed?)

Comment: There is a "Simulate Memory Warning" under hardware option in the simulator's menu. Application's `-applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:` & `UIViewController`'s `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` methods are used in this scenario.

Comment: Looks like a good approach to me. I wish a similar option was there on actual devices. Thanks @staticVoidMan!

Comment: this answer seems to do the trick on device -- [answer link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8727632/2857130)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Development: How can I induce low memory warnings on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717138/ios-development-how-can-i-induce-low-memory-warnings-on-device)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to test how the app recovers from sudden termination (as opposed to how it handles the termination) then the easiest way to kill the app is to stop the debugging session with xcode.

Just Build And Run while the app is running, and you get an instant recovery test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on handling termination